# make a list in scheme with high efficiency

Tags: performance, list, recursion, scheme, racket

I want to use the Scheme language to create a special list with high efficiency. E.g.:

> Function name: `make-list`
>     parameter: `max`
>     `(make-list max) -> (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ... max)`

I can complete this task by using recursion method.

```
#lang racket

(define (make-list max)
(define lst '())
(define count 1) 
(make-list-helper lst max count))

(define (make-list-helper lst max count) 
 (cond  
 [(> count max) lst]
 [else 
  (set! lst (append lst (list count))) 
  (make-list-helper lst max (add1 count)]))
```

However, this method can be considered to be low. I have no idea how to improve its efficiency of making a list. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: I know it may not be applicable in your case, but you can take a look at Lazy Racket, because these kind of lists don't have to be built till they're really needed.

Comment: BTW, there's no good reason to use `set!` in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another definition of "efficiency" might be: writing the procedure with the least amount of code. With that in mind, the shortest solution for the question would be to use an existing procedure to solve the problem; for example if `max = 10`:

```
(define (make-list max-val)
  (build-list max-val add1))

(make-list 10)
=> '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
```

The above makes use of the [build-list](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=build-list#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._build-list%29%29) procedure that's part of Racket:

> Creates a list of n elements by applying proc to the integers from `0` to `(sub1 n)` in order. If lst is the resulting list, then `(list-ref lst i)` is the value produced by `(proc i)`.

Yet another option, also for Racket, would be to use [iterations and comprehensions](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/for.html):

```
(define (make-list max-val)
  (for/list ([i (in-range 1 (add1 max-val))]) i))

(make-list 10)
=> '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
```

Either way, given that the procedures are part of the language's core libraries, you can be sure that their performance is quite good, no need to worry about that unless a profiler indicates that they're a bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

The key principle is to avoid [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html), which you don't: using `append` repeatedly takes more and more as the list becomes longer. Prepending the element is O(1), while appending is O(length of list); so make the innermost `make-list-helper` return a singular list `(max)`, and use `cons` to prepend elements on recursion.

(I would prefer iterative solution, but I'm a common lisper, so I'd better avoid insisting on *anything* for scheme).

No code included to avoid spoiling you the fun of learning.

Answer (score 2):

```
(define (make-list max)
  (let f ((i max)(a '()))
    (if (zero? i)
        a
        (f (- i 1) (cons i a)))))
```

This seems to be a simple exercise for iteration.

The above is as simple as it gets, and you will use it every where in Scheme.

Make sure you understand how the entire snippet works.